# MySQL cluster table is not being replicated on data nodes

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-cluster

I created MySQL cluster by using [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-a-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04/) guide:

From management node:

```
ndb_mgm
show
```

Output:

```
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=2    @10.0.2.5  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12, Nodegroup: 0, *)
id=3    @10.0.2.6  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @10.0.2.4  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @10.0.2.7  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12)
id=5    @10.0.2.6  (mysql-5.6.31 ndb-7.4.12)
```

> I have created database from `10.0.2.7`. But, cannot see database on data nodes.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Databases don't show up on data nodes. Create a database
on 10.0.2.7 (MySQL Server) and it will also show up on
10.0.2.6 (MySQL Server). The actual database is stored
on data nodes, but are only seen from MySQL Servers.